# Automator "Set PDF metadata" window size?

Tags: automator, pdf, metadata

I have a workflow in automator that "receives a selected PDF file in Finder", then "Open finder items", follow by "Set PDF Metadata"

When running the workflow, "Set PDF Metadata" opens a window that takes some inputs (title, author, and so on), and then requires me to press "Continue" to move on the next step of the workflow.

**The window that "Set PDF Metadata" opens is always partially minimized, so I have to manually resize it bigger every time I run the workflow.** Is there some way I can specify the size and position that the window should open at?

To replicate this behavior a simple workflow that goes as follows should work:

1. Get specified finder item, and specify a PDF file
2. Open finder items (open with default application)
3. Set PDF metadata, with the "Title" and "Author" boxes checked

Further information and screenshots:
Default PDF application is Preview

OS is MacOS Sierra 10.13.3

Comment: I don’t get a window.  After checking the relevant boxes and entering information into the fields, the PDF metadata just gets set, without a separate window manifesting.  You’re going to need to be more specific about how this comes about for you: MacOS version, your default PDF program, a screenshot or two.

Comment: @CJK, If when the **Automator Service** runs, the **Set PDF Metadata** _action's dialog_ shows, then in the **Options** of the **Set PDF Metadata** _action_, the **Show this action when the workflow runs** check box is checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to set the *position* and *size* of the **Set PDF Metadata** *action's* window when run from an **Automator Service**, however it requires a bit of a creative workaround.

I have tested the following and it works for me under **macOS High Sierra**.

There are two primary components for this process, one being the **Automator Service** named **Edit PDF Metadata**, and the other, an **AppleScript** application that sets the `position` and `size` of the **Set PDF Metadata** *action's* `window`.

For the **Automator Service**, which I saved as **Edit PDF Metadata**, the image below shows the settings.

- Note that the **PDF** document does not first have to be opened to set the *metadata* and why there is no **Open Finder Items** *action*. If you were doing it the see information in the document as a reference to be used in the **Set PDF Metadata** *action*, you can add it back in.

Example *code* for the **Run Shell Script** *action*:

```
open -a "/Applications/Resize Set PDF Metadata Window.app"
echo "$1"
```

- Note that the *fully qualified pathname* to the **app** does not necessarily need to be used and the `open` *command* could be shortened to `open -a "Resize Set PDF Metadata Window"`. Then it doesn't matter where the **Resize Set PDF Metadata Window.app** is saved, it's found automatically. I've include the *fully qualified pathname* just so there was no ambiguity.

[image: Automator Service]

Next, the desired *position* and *size* of the *window* for the **Set PDF Metadata** *action* needs to be determined:

In **Script Editor**, open a new document with the following **AppleScript** *code*, but do not run it yet, just have it ready.

```
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    get {position, size} of window 1 ¬
        of process "com.apple.automator.runner"
```

Now in **Finder**, select a **PDF** document and right-click selecting **Edit PDF Metadata** from the **Services** *section* of the *context menu*.

Then position and resize the **Set PDF Metadata** *action's* window on the screen as wanted, leaving it on screen for the time being, then back in **Script Editor**, run the *code* you prepped to get the desired `position` and `size` of the `window` for the **Set PDF Metadata** *action*.

On my system it returned, e.g.: `{{870, 280}, {700, 290}}`, on my 27" Thunderbolt Display.

Make note of the `results` for use with the *code*, which is used next, to create the **Resize Set PDF Metadata Window.app** in **Script Editor**.

You can now click the **Cancel** button on the **Set PDF Metadata** *action's* window, as it has served its purpose to this point.

Now create the **Resize Set PDF Metadata Window.app** in **Script Editor** using the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set i to 0
    repeat until (exists window 1 of process "com.apple.automator.runner")
        delay 0.1
        set i to i + 1
        if i > 30 then return
    end repeat
    tell window 1 of process "com.apple.automator.runner"
        set position to {870, 280}
        set size to {700, 290}
    end tell
end tell
```

- Change the *value* of `set position to` and `set size to` as appropriate and save as an application named **Resize Set PDF Metadata Window** in the `/Applications` folder.
- Note that on my system `30`, in `if i > 30 then return`, equates to `~5` seconds and is used so `repeat until` is not an *endless loop*, if something happens and `window 1 of process "com.apple.automator.runner"` doesn't appear for some reason.

Before really using the new **Automator Service** for the first time, you need to add **Resize Set PDF Metadata Window.app** to: **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**

With that done, **Edit PDF Metadata** is ready to used on a **PDF** document in **Finder** from the **Services** *section* of the *context menu*. It is also available from the **Finder** > **Services** menu as well. Also a keyboard shortcut can be assigned to the *service* in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** > **Files and Folders**

Also note that by default, the *metadata* added to the selected **PDF** document is automatically saved upon pressing the **Continue** button, so there is no need to use the **Quit Application** *action* set to **Preview** with the **[√] Ask to save changes** check box clicked. That is unless you added the **Open Finder Items** *action*, then add back the **Quit Application** *action* set to **Preview** too. (Note that **Ask to save changes** did not work in my testing.)

---

**NOTE:** Use **caution** with the **Rename PDF Documents** *action*, because if the **Title** *check box* is checked in the **Set PDF Metadata** *action's* window but *text box* is left blank, it will delete the **PDF** document upon clicking the **Continue** button! (This appears to be a bug in this *action* under **macOS High Sierra**.) Additionally, if you set the **Title** to the name of an existing **PDF** document, while the *metadata* is changed, nonetheless the target file is not renamed. **As always, insure you have proper backups before running automated services upon your files.**

---

The only drawback to this method that I can think of, is that only one **Automator Service** can be run at a time, this one, otherwise it will not be able to get window 1 of process "com.apple.automator.runner" if there is more than one "com.apple.automator.runner" *process* running. But how often does one really need to have more then one **Automator Service** run at a time.

---

If you do not want to have the **Dock Tile** for the **Resize Set PDF Metadata Window.app** show on the **Dock**, then in **Terminal** use the following *command*:

```
defaults write '/Applications/Resize Set PDF Metadata Window.app/Contents/Info.plist' LSUIElement -bool yes
```

Afterwards, you can use the *command* with `-bool no` to have to have the *app's* **Dock Tile** show on the **Dock**.

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not employ any *error handling* and is meant only to show one of many ways accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.

Comment: What a great answer.  Such excellent detail.

Comment: Thank you very much for the great answer. I have two questions though: 1) Since we are running the script to resize the window **before** the dialogue window is actually opened, does this mean that theres some background process(com.apple.automator.runner?) that dictates the position and size of open dialogue windows? 2) What is the purpose of the **echo "$1"$** after the open command? The AppleScript looks like it does everything, so is this **echo** just executing the script (perhaps since we are passing inputs as arguments?)

Comment: @majmun, The _process_ `com.apple.automator.runner` is the _process_ that's running the **Automator** _service workflow_ and exists before any _actions_ are processed. `window 1 of process "com.apple.automator.runner"` is the window that appears when the **Set PDF Metadata** _action_ is triggered. By using the `open` _command_ with the **Resize Set PDF Metadata Window.app** in the the **Run Shell Script** _action_, this enables the ability to resize the window when it does appear, which is also why it has to run first and loop until the window does appear. Continued in next comment...

Comment: @majmun, Without the functionality provided by the `open` _command_, the prompt immediately returning allowing further _code_ to be processed independent of what `open` executed, and the _code_ used in the **Resize Set PDF Metadata Window.app**, there is no other way I know of or can think of off the top of my head that will do as you have asked. The `echo "$1"` is absolutely necessary to pass the _input argument_, the _fully qualified pathname_ of the **PDF** document selected in **Finder**, in the case, to the **Set PDF Metadata** _action_.  Continued in next comment...

Comment: @majmun, One thing I left out of the **Run Shell Script** _action_, because it wasn't needed on my system, was a delay between the `open` _command_ and the `echo` command, e.g. `sleep 1`, to insure the **AppleScript** _app_ was fully running before the **Set PDF Metadata** _action_ is triggered. On a slower system this could be necessary, but obviously it's working for you without and I'm mentioning it more so if it's needed for someone else using this type of workaround.