# Applescript: Help with idle and hiding from finder?

Tags: finder, applescript

I'm trying to get my script that works to do 2 things: run in the background every 60 seconds, and disappear from the finder and the dock.

Original:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set process_list to the name of every process
    if "QuickLookUIService" is in process_list then
        set ThePID to unix id of process "QuickLookUIService"
        do shell script "kill -KILL " & ThePID

    end if

end tell
```

When I try the following code for idle, the script stops working.

```
on idle

    tell application "System Events"
        set process_list to the name of every process
        if "QuickLookUIService" is in process_list then
            set ThePID to unix id of process "QuickLookUIService"
            do shell script "kill -KILL " & ThePID

        end if

    end tell
return 60
end idle
```

And when I add this code to hide from finder, nothing happens. Ideas?

```
tell application "Finder"

    set visible of process "killQuickLook" to false

end tell
```

Comment: Don't. Use launchd.

Comment: @JBis, I agree with your comment however, you might want to expound a bit more on it (maybe in an answer) as Eric McClellan might not know about `launchd`.

Comment: @Eric McClellan, Are you running this AppleScript code as a script, or an application?

Comment: @Eric McClellan, If running as an application, then to hide the Dock Tile... have a look at ... "If you do not want to have the Dock Tile for ..." Near the bottom of my answer [A: Automator “Set PDF metadata” window size?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317090/automator-set-pdf-metadata-window-size/317125?s=2|5.6596#317125) for how to hide the Dock Tile when the application is running. That said though, I'd turn off the service vs. killing it every `n seconds`! Hopefully JBis will post the info on that or provide a link.

Comment: @Eric McClellan, BTW In order for the `idle` _handler_ to work, the _script_ must be saved as an _application_ and the **[√] Stay open after run handler** checkbox checked during the save process. Have a look at: [idle and quit Handlers for Stay-Open Applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-SW7)

Comment: Since you end up executing a `do shell script` command anyway, you can replace your entire AppleScript code under "Original:" with this: `do shell script "pkill -KILL QuickLookUIService"`.  No need for _System Events_, etc. which means you might as well be using an actual shell script instead of AppleScript.  That said, killing the service off periodically like this is going to be a drain on your resources.  I think you need a different tactic.

Comment: Found [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8506070), which is the `launchd` implementation of your objective.  Explains how to do it step-by-step, and supplies you the necessary code (XML).

Comment: Thanks everyone! I'm running it as an application that stays open after run.  I'm trying your solutions now and will get back in a few minutes.

Comment: Ok, edits to the applescript worked great. I ended up going with the launchd implementation as suggested by @CJK. Thanks folks! Now my battery on my 2017 MBP lasts for more than 90 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stumbled across [this link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8506070) that provides a step-by-step guide to implementing the solution to this problem using `launchd`.

For convenience, I've copied and formatted the relevant contents of the linked page below.

> ### How to fix QuickLookUIService memory/CPU issues in High Sierra
>
> If you're having issues with high memory (or CPU) usage on High Sierra, this is the result of a bug with the QuickLookUIService which appears to have been introduced in that version and which unfortunately has not yet been fixed. The only workaround right now is to repeatedly force quit the `quicklookuiservice`.
>
> 1. Create a new file in your favourite text editor (if you use Apple's *Text Edit*, make sure the file is in plain text format)
> 2. Paste the xml at the end of these steps into the file
> 3. Rename the file to the same as what's within the `<string>` tags with a `.plist` extension (in my example, `com.zerowidth.launched.killquicklook.plist`)
> 4. Copy the file to your library in the `LaunchAgents` folder (in Finder you can use *Go > Go to folder > /Users/[yourusername]/Library/LaunchAgents*. You may need to type an administrator password to authorize this action
> 5. After your next login/restart, you should find the memory issues caused by this to be back to normal. If you ever want to remove the service, just delete the plist file
>
> #### Some explanation of what this does
>
> A launch agent is a service that helps manage applications in Mac OS. In this case, we've written our own small launch agent program that kills the quicklook service repeatedly at an interval (the `killall -9 -v QuickLookUIService` part). The name of the service is within the  tags (you can call it what you like) and the interval is within the `<integer>` tags (in my case, 5600 seconds). Feel free to change the interval to whatever works best for you (if you set it higher, it will interfere less with your normal use of preview, but also allow the service to use more memory). As a final note, bear in mind that if you are previewing a document when the service restarts, the preview will fail (you can just preview again immediately).
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
> <plist version="1.0">
>     <dict>
>         <key>Label</key>
>         <string>com.zerowidth.launched.killquicklook</string>
>         <key>ProgramArguments</key>
>         <array>
>             <string>sh</string>
>             <string>-c</string>
>             <string>killall -9 -v QuickLookUIService</string>
>         </array>
>         <key>StartInterval</key>
>         <integer>5600</integer>
>     </dict>
> </plist>
> ```

---

<sup>**Note:** *Expanded to answer from comment dated Dec 10 '18 at 20:29*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @CJK for the solution I ended up using... creating a launch agent: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8506070

Super helpful step-by-step even if you don't know anything about launch agents.

using the launch agent version of this fix keeps from taxing additional system resources. My battery life basically tripled or quadrupled now that the buggy, energy-sapping quicklookhelper gets shut down quickly.

Comment: You might want to expand a little bit on your answer; the system thinks it's low quality. Why and how did this solve your problem? See [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/295232)